# What Webpack's HMR can do which Browsersync is not able to do?

Tags: node.js, webpack, browser-sync, webpack-style-loader, webpack-hmr

I use Browsersync for Automatic Page refresh for my HTML, CSS changes without reloading the whole page and it works. It also doesn't page to the top to apply the changes and keep the state of the element persistent too, for example, input text.

Is there anything better and useful Webpack's Hot module reload feature can do which Browsersync can't, but with particular use case and project with specific frameworks, where Browsersync is not capable?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack's HMR allows all kinds of modules to be updated at runtime without the need for a full refresh. Browsersync does a full page refresh when JS is changed. CSS is injected directly.

Both are used for different use cases. e.g. Webpack alone cannot synchronize pages on different devices.